# Shimano Deore Squeaking Sound

Tags: brakes

Any suggestions on how to reduce/eliminate the squeaking sound on my Shimano V-brakes? I dont remember doing anything, i just wipe my bike and rims every after ride.

Comment: Generally this means you need to "toe in" the pads.  Sometimes you need to replace the pads with a different material.

Comment: Check out the related questions to the right. You'll find a lot of good info about squeaky brakes in there.

Comment: Toe-ing in sometimes helps along with cleaning the rims with citrus cleaner or isopropanol (and making sure the pads are of decent quality).

Answer (score 1):

Check if there is any mud in brake pads.
Try cleaning the rims with alcohol :)
Read this http://www.bikeforums.net/mountain-biking/45251-cleaning-rims-alcohol-benzine-solvent.html